# Path to XML-File (Filter) for Findbugs-Plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, findbugs

Could someone know where is saved path to external XML-File that contain configuration for Findbugs-Plugin in Eclipse. May it be somewhere in .prefs files? (I'm asking for path to file xml-file that I can include in: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Findbugs -> File filters -> Include file filters).

Thanks for all hints,
greetings,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Findbugs settings are saved in the file:

```
[WORKSPACE]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/edu.umd.cs.findbugs.plugin.eclipse.prefs
```

You find your current workspace folder here: *Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Configuration -> System properties ->* Parameter *-data*